# Filtrar um Array de nomes e retornar o(s) maior(s) nome(s)

Tags: javascript

Eu estou com um objeto `JSON` de um formulário, então converti normalmente e criei um `map` apenas com os nomes dos usuários dentro de uma `array`. O próximo passo que preciso fazer é analisar todos os nomes e pegar o(s) que tem o maior `length`.

Já tentei usar `filter` e `reduce`, mas sempre dá algum tipo de erro, alguém poderia me dizer qual algoritmo devo usar?

```
Const nomes =["Luan","Pedro","Caio", "Mariana", "Lígia", "Rafaela"]
```

O resultado deve ser uma array com o(s) nome(s) de maior `length`.

Comment: certo entendi sua dúvida, porem a partir de qual length você deseja atribuir a esse novo array de nomes?

Comment: Se uma resposta resolver seu problema marque-a como aceita. Veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx7Ts.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 4):

Encontramos o nome de maior comprimento de um item da matriz com a função `reduce`  e, em seguida, filtramos o array com os elementos que têm esse comprimento com a função `filter`. Ele nos retorna vários elementos se eles tiverem o mesmo comprimento mais longo

```js
const nomes =["Luan","Pedro","Caio", "Mariana", "Lígia", "Rafaela"];

ln = nomes.reduce((r,s) => r > s.length ? r : s.length, 0);

const result = nomes.filter(pl => pl.length == ln);

console.log(result);
```

Se houver mais de uma string de `maior length` na matriz, retornará uma matriz deles. Se houver apenas um com `maior length`, retornará a string e não uma matriz.

**1 - exemplo com um nome de `maior length`**

```js
const nomes = ["Luan","Pedro","Caio", "Mariana", "Lígia", "Rafaela", "Andrei Coelho"];
var todosArr = [];

function stringsMaisCompridas(arr) {
    var tlength = 0;
    for(var i =0; i < nomes.length; i++){
      if(tlength < nomes[i].length){
        tlength = nomes[i].length;
      }
    }
    for(var j =0; j < nomes.length; j++){
      if(nomes[j].length == tlength){
         todosArr.push(nomes[j]);
      }
    }
   if(todosArr.length == 1){
     return todosArr[0]
   }else{
      return todosArr
  }
}


console.log(stringsMaisCompridas(nomes));
```

**2 - exemplo com mais de um `maior length`**

```js
const nomes = ["Luan","Pedro","Caio", "Mariana", "Lígia", "Rafaela", "Andrei Coelho", "Fulano Santos", "Ciclano Pedra"];
var todosArr = [];

function stringsMaisCompridas(arr) {
    var tlength = 0;
    for(var i =0; i < nomes.length; i++){
      if(tlength < nomes[i].length){
        tlength = nomes[i].length;
      }
    }
    for(var j =0; j < nomes.length; j++){
      if(nomes[j].length == tlength){
         todosArr.push(nomes[j]);
      }
    }
   if(todosArr.length == 1){
     return todosArr[0]
   }else{
      return todosArr
  }
}


console.log(stringsMaisCompridas(nomes));
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua contribuição <3

Answer (score 2):

Bem primeiro eu recebo o array de nomes na variavel `arrayOne`, depois eu pego o primeiro item desse array e atribuo o length dele em uma variavel, `nameLength`.
  Depois eu fiz um `map` em meu `arrayOne` e vejo os nomes que tem o tamanho maior que minha variavel `nameLength` eu dou um push no novo array `arrayTwo` que é o array dos maiores nomes. E caso o length do nome seja menor eu só dou um console avisando.

```
var arrayOne = ["Luan","Pedro","Caio", "Mariana", "Lígia", "Rafaela"];
var nameLength = arrayOne[0].length;
var arrayTwo = [];
arrayOne.map(name =>{
    name.length > 4 ? arrayTwo.push(name) : console.log("length menor") ;
})

console.log(arrayTwo);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua contribuição <3